# Injected SVG losing dimensions

Tags: javascript, svg

Attempting to inject SVG elements with raw javascript.  I can inspect and see the elements have been loaded, but dimensions end up being 0x0 instead of the size set on the element.

```
   (function() {
  // Constructor
  this.Loading = function() {

        this.svgNamespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";

    var svg = createSvgObject("svg", "loaderSvg");
    svg.setAttributeNS(null, "width", 200);
    svg.setAttributeNS(null, "height", 200);
    document.getElementById("possibleLoadingLocation").appendChild(svg);
    var circle = createSvgObject("circle", "test");
    circle.setAttribute("cx", 40);
    circle.setAttribute("cy", 40);
    circle.setAttribute("r", 30);
    circle.setAttribute("stroke", "#000");
    circle.setAttribute("stroke-width", 2);
    circle.setAttribute("fill", "#f00");
    svg.appendChild(circle);
  }

  function createSvgObject(elementType, elementId) {
    if (elementType === undefined || elementType == null) {
      throw "elementType is required to createSvgObject";
    }
    var element = document.createElementNS(this.svgNamespace, elementType);
    if (elementId != null) {
      element.setAttributeNS(null, "id", elementId);
    }
    return element
  }


}());
var myLoading = new Loading();
```

Both the SVG object and the Circle object arrive with dimensions of 0x0.  I have used css in the below example to force the svg to match the dimensions of the div containing it.  I have also copied the exact svg code from the inspection into the body without css where I can see it sizing properly.

Thanks for any help.

**https://jsfiddle.net/t92m5L8s/3/**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the location of

```
 this.svgNamespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
```

to before:

```
this.Loading = function() {
```